# how to check the font style file in VS code

Tags: flutter

```
fonts:
- family: Overlock
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/Overlock-Regular.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Overlock-Italic.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Overlock-Black.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Overlock-BlackItalic.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Overlock-Bold.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Overlock-BoldItalic.ttf
```

and when I open the ttf files to check the font style in VS code I get this error :

> The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.

Kindly help with this

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is important in `pubspec.yaml` file. Looks like your indentation isn't correct. Here is the example of using custom font

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

[Details Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts)